# Char & behaviour on controls

Tags: vb.net, dotnetbar

Currerently I face strange behaviour on my controls when text is present either on `advlistbox` items or `buttonx` and probably rest as well. This happens when i use `&` charackter within string. For instance when i use double `&&` it shows single one. Another example when i put e.g `&&&something` then it shows &something with s - underscored. Is there anyone whom knows what is going on and how can i avoid that situation?

Answer (score 2):

A double ampersand is used to escape the default behavior of an ampersand relative to controls. When an ampersand precedes control text it underlines the following character, usually to denote that controls hotkey. In the case of your triple ampersand situation you are using the right most ampersand as the underline and the remaining 2 as an escape so that a literal ampersand is displayed in your controls text.

If your goal is to literally display 2 ampersands then you must supply your control text with a total of 4 consecutive ampersands. (`&&&&`)

Comment: so what should i do in case i have in db this one: Betten & Liegen but in advlistbox i see: Betten _Liegen or in db i have Eck- & Sitzbänke and in advlistbox i see: Eck-_Sitzbänke  . Can you tell me how can i fix that situation or what to do? My client require to use it. Please dont tell me to everytime check what's in database and then convert it to the proper form this would be very annoying especially if probably i cannot imagine all user behaviours and will.

Comment: @JimmyJimm If you want an ampersand to appear in your controls text then you must provide it with 2 (`&&`)

Comment: i found one solution to false this property UseMnemonic which is available for buttonx but i cannot see it for advlistbox

Comment: @JimmyJimm You could extend the listbox control and apply the property yourself

Comment: can you provide some solution how can i do this best way as i have 'thousand of places' where i would have to do that replacment,

Comment: @JimmyJimm I'd recommend posting a new question about your new issue as that goes beyond the scope of this question

Comment: so simply saying is always to loop through database e.g DataTable then find if there is & and replace to && so listbox will show it correctly? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: @JimmyJimm : You could always use a Regex for every string you read: `Dim Replaced As String = Regex.Replace(<input here>, "(?<!\&)\&(?!\&)", "&&")`

Comment: @JimmyJimm : Although I just remembered that the Regex solution only work for single ampersands. What is `advlistbox` by the way, a normal `Windows.Forms.ListBox`? Your question lacks a bit of detail. Do like _Up All Night_ said and create a custom control of the ListBox where you override the mnemonics. Try overriding the `ProcessMnemonic()` method and make it always return False.

Comment: no this is AdvListBox from DotNetBar (Devcomponenets) controls. I do not see there useMnemonic property. How to say to this control to force UseMnemonic to false?

Comment: Otherwise its really much work for me to always convert and then convert back strings as if i show after convertion correctly then i have to convert back when user e.g want to remove it from listbox as then it appears double & instead of one. So imagine if i have hundreds places where i want to be sure to convert when show and then to convert back for code to do some staff. Is there any way to change behaviour of control itself? If you need an info about this control let me know.

Comment: i just noticed this control contains nice property called:  LB_SubSections.ProcessMnemonicEx() which takes as an argument char. What does it mean? Can i just on form load say  LB_SubSections.ProcessMnemonicEx("&") ?? Then it will be alert for control to not process this or?